# Flutter Error : The argument type 'List<CameraDescription>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<CameraDescription>'

Tags: flutter

I got an error to assign data on my widget.

My widget "_getPreview" requires List type and I assign snapshot.data(I think it's List type), but has error.

For the novice, that's a hard problem to solve. :(

Help me please.

```
class _TakePhotoState extends State<TakePhoto> {

  late CameraController _controller;
  Widget _progress = MyProgressIndicator();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>>(
      future: availableCameras(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: size!.width,
              height: size!.width,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: (snapshot.hasData)?_getPreview(snapshot.data):_progress, // <- The error is here

            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Icon(Icons.camera, color: Colors.white),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  primary: Colors.blue, // <-- Button color
                  onPrimary: Colors.red, // <-- Splash color
                ),
              )
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }

  Widget _getPreview(List<CameraDescription> cameras) {
    _controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _controller.initialize(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return CameraPreview(
              _controller,
          );
        } else {
          return _progress;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
child: (snapshot.hasData)?_getPreview(snapshot.data):_progress, // <- The error is here
```

The error is basically saying that `snapshot.data` can be `null`. And `_getPreview()` can only accept **non null value** .. So to let your code know that `snapshot.data` can never be null... Do `_getPreview(snapshot.data!)`

Comment: Thank you very much noobslayer! It's solved very well.

Comment: Consider marking this as a right answer if it helped you